# jQuery Replace after Append Not Work

Tags: jquery

I have the code to add something in the html tag with jQuery. If I write the code directly in the form of html. for example like this: `<span id='target'></span>` then able to walk normally.

But I do not have access to do that, so I need to add from the outside and I think jQuery is the best choice.
This turned out to fail.

**My code:**

```
<div class="namediv">
<span class="box"></span>
</div>

<script>
var sender=[
'https://www.blogger.com/profile/12661450765726347282'
];

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.box').append("<span id='target'></span>")
});

for(var v=0; v<sender.length; v=v+1){
 $("a[href='"+sender[v]+"']").each(function(){
 $(this).closest(".namediv")
 .find("#target").replaceWith("<span id='bySender'>Author</span>");
 })
}
</script>
```

There is a solution?

Comment: Creating multiple elements on one page with the same id will get you in trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the replacing code part into the dom ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.box').append("<span id='target'></span>");
  for(var v=0; v<sender.length; v=v+1){
   $("a[href='"+sender[v]+"']").each(function(){
     $(this).closest(".namediv").find("#target")
     .replaceWith("<span id='bySender'>Author</span>");
   });
  }
});
```

If you do not do like this, then the for loop will be executed first. So eventually it will yield unexpected results.